# array of pointers to class method error c++11

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I got a small "problem" with array of pointers to class method.

In short:
My class Complex has four functions - `double funX(void)`:

```
double fun1(void) const {...}
double fun2(void) const {...}
...
```

Then I have and array of pointers to member functions of above recipe.

```
double (Complex::*arr_ptr_fun[4])(void) const;
```

I initialize this array in constructor initializer list:

```
... : re(_re), im(_im), arr_ptr_fun{&fun1,&fun2,&fun3,&fun4} { /*EMPTY*/ }
```

When I try to call any of these 4 functions via this array e.g.:

```
std::cout << this->*arr_ptr_fun[0]();
```

I get an error I do not understand:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((const Complex*)this)->Complex::arr_ptr_fun[0] (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((const Complex*)this)->Complex::arr_ptr_fun[0]) (...)'
     double fun4(void) const {std::cout << this->*arr_ptr_fun[0](); return sqrt(fun3());}
```

Use `.*` or `->*` via which pointer...? (`chaos *` Universe pointer?)

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tried compiling it myself because you didn't post enough code to make it compilable but the error looks like the compiler is confused and needs parenthesis: `std::cout << (this->*arr_ptr_fun[0])();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to surround the member function pointer in parenthesis,

```cpp
std::cout << (this->*arr_ptr_fun[0])();
```

Comment: Thanks, that solver in-class usage, but what about other scopes?
e.g. this:
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Complex& c) 
{ 
    os << (c.*arr_ptr_fun[0])(); 
    return os;
}

error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Complex::arr_ptr_fun'
double (Complex::*arr_ptr_fun[4])(void) const;

Comment: @Steve, I believe that's because arr_ptr_fun is not a static member variable. You'll need to reference the member in `c`. Try this: `os << (c.*(c.arr_ptr_fun[0]))();`. That being said, if `arr_ptr_fun` is the same for every instance of `Complex`, then there's no problem making it static.

Comment: Wow, that worked, but how come? Use variable name twice? If I had array of objects, I would have to write (arr[0].*(arr[0].arr_ptr_fun[0]))() ?

Comment: @Steve, `arr_ptr_fun` is an instance member of `Complex`, so you'll need an instance of `Complex`, in this case `c` to get the array. If you have an array of Complex objects, then yes you'll have to do that. Alternatively, if you make `arr_ptr_fun` static in `Complex`, then you can get away with `(arr[0].*(Complex::arr_ptr_fun[0]))()`. Of course, that assumes that `arr_ptr_fun` will always be `[&Complex::fun1, &Complex::fun2, &Complex::fun3, &Complex::fun4]`.

Comment: Thanks million times :) I had to understand this. I had a class that cointains  array of 10 Complex, and I tried to make << write all 4 funcions of each object, and now I got it working: 
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const tab_complex& tc) { for (auto&& x : tc.tab_c) for (auto&& y : x.tab_wsk_fun) os << (x.*y)() << std::endl; return os;}

Answer (score 5):

The answer given by @Aldehir is the correct answer to your specific question. However, if you are using C++11 (or later) then it might be a lot more convenient to use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to wrap calls to member functions. Using `std::mem_fn` you can eliminate the issues associated with `.*` and `->*`. Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/606b3d7ef041364c):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

class Complex
{
public:
    double fun1() const {return 1;}
    double fun2() const {return 2;}
    double fun3() const {return 3;}
    double fun4() const {return 4;}

    using MemFun = decltype(std::mem_fn(&Complex::fun1)) ;
    static const std::array<MemFun, 4> arr_ptr_fun ;
} ;

const std::array<Complex::MemFun, 4> Complex::arr_ptr_fun {{
    std::mem_fn(&Complex::fun1),
    std::mem_fn(&Complex::fun2),
    std::mem_fn(&Complex::fun3),
    std::mem_fn(&Complex::fun4)
}} ;

int main()
{
    //
    // Call all the member functions using object my_foo.
    //
    Complex my_foo ;
    for(auto func: Complex::arr_ptr_fun) 
    {
        std::cout << func(my_foo) << std::endl;
    }
    //
    // The same as above but using array indexing. 
    //
    for(size_t i=0; i<Complex::arr_ptr_fun.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << Complex::arr_ptr_fun[i](my_foo) << std::endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```